# -ms-text-security:disc and -ms-text-security:disc; not working

Tags: browser, html, css

`-ms-text-security:disc` and `-moz-text-security:dis`c is not working for IE and mozilla. Is there any other way around? I want to use it mask text field with bullets. `-webkit-text-security:dis`c is working for chrome.

Comment: https://github.com/noppa/text-security

Answer (score 0):

As per --webkit-text-security property is only applicable to those browsers using the WebKit as the engine.